# As redis keeps data in memory, what can be the maximum size of data stored in Redis

Tags: redis, nosql

I don't know much about redis, but what I know is Redis stores data in key-value format in memory and data is also persistent as stored in disk in intervals.

So I want to know, Let say if the RAM is 10GB, then can we store data in redis more than 10GB?

In fact, I am not much clear with the disk and memory usages that redis use to store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Redis FAQ](http://redis.io/topics/faq):

> Redis is an in-memory but persistent on disk database, so it represents a different trade off where very high write and read speed is achieved **with the limitation of data sets that can't be larger than memory**.

So, unfortunately, no, your datasize is limited to the amount of RAM you've allowed Redis to use.

Comment: Thanks @Will, I think that's major difference between MongoDB and Redis as a NoSQL database. Ofcourse there are many more differences, but that's a big.

Answer (score 4):

Situation is even worse. If you have 10GB of RAM then in fact you can store about 6-7GB. It is for at least two reasons:

1. Redis has certain memory overhead per a data item.
2. Redis forks in order to do snapshots. Which results in allocation of additional memory for all of the pages that have been changing during that process.

Comment: Yeah @denis, actually that doesn't matter if its less thant 10GB. I was just wondering whether we can store more than 10 GB. So redis can never be used as a primary database.

Comment: Try Tarantool http://tarantool.org. It is also in-memory, but it uses memory much more efficient, so you can be sure that the 10Gb is the real 10Gb. If it is still not enough then you should take a look to MySQL or Postgres.